# How to seperate an address string mashed together in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I have an address string in MySQL that has been mashed together from the source.  I think it is possible to use a regular expression or some other method to seperate the string into usable parts in MySQL, but I am not aware of how this could be acheived.

Basically each string looks something like these examples (I have added a marker to the top to show what each bit is):

```
<-------------><-------><-><-->
123 Fake StreetRESERVOIRVIC3001
<-----------------><--------------------><------><-><-->
Brooks Nursing Home123 Little Fake StreetSMITHTONNSW2001
<-------------------><-------------------><--- ><><-->
Grange Police StationShop 1 Fairytale LaneGRANGEWA8001
```

The address supposed to be broken up into optionally two lines of address information, suburb, state and post code.  I'm in Australia so the state will be either NSW,VIC,QLD,WA,SA,NT or ACT and the postcode will always be a 4 digit number at the very end.

The possible ways to break it up are that the suburb will always be capitalised, the state and postcode will be predicatable within the last 6 or 7 characters (depending on state) and the first two lines of address information will be broken up by a change in case with no space character in between.

I have some 100,000 records like this, so to go through and do it by hand would be very time consuming.  Any help on a way of doing this programatically would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when someone comes up with "123 McDonald's Way?" There's a change of case that isn't an address part boundary.

Comment: I would repost this with your favorite scripting language tag something like perl, or python, or sed and awk instead of mysql. You are going to have real problems separating the first two fields. A programming language would be a better way to attack this.

Answer (score 1):

With no spaces? Most gross...

MySQL doesn't have the tools to deal with that, so you'll have to access the database with an external program. I tend to use Perl for manipulations like this.

Start from the end and work backwards... we know the last four should be digits, and the letters preceding that one of 7 options. Use that knowledge and you'll be down 2 fields and 6-7 characters.

It looks like your example now has a town in all capital letters at the end... Parse out that, and it should match to the state and area code. I'm certain you can find a database of zip codes within some minutes online.

With the name and street address remaining, that will have some variability to it, and I wish you a bit of luck there. You may have a head-start with being able to concentrate on the lack of a space between a lowercase and capital, or a letter and number as a breaking point.

Answer (score 0):

Challenge accepted. I'll even throw in some basic punctuation to allow for "101 St. Mark's St." and the like.

```
/^(([\w\'\.](?=[a-z \'\.])| )+[a-z\'\.])?(([\w\'\.](?=[a-z \d\'\.])| )+[a-z\.\'])([A-Z]+)(NSW|VIC|QLD|WA|SA|NT|ACT)(\d{4})/
```

Could probably use a little more clean-up, but it should work in any language which supports basic regex with lookahead (some implementations, like JavaScript's and (I think) Ruby's, support lookahead, but not lookbehind). (That, and this puzzle kept me up well past my bed time.) At the very least, it worked on the three examples you provided.

By the way, [2problems.com](http://2problems.com/) is a great site for quickly testing regular expressions. It's what I used to work this puzzle out. The guy who built it must have been a real genius. *(koff koff)*

[Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/) is another good option, though since it works by making Ajax calls to a Ruby script behind-the-scenes, it's a bit slower. It does have the nice feature of being able to link to entered patterns and haystacks, though; [here's this pattern on Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/OswWpnFLO4). The 2problems guy really should get around to implementing something like that some day.